# Convert unicode string representation of emoji to unicode emoji in python

Tags: python, unicode, pyspark, emoji

I'm using Python2 on Spark (PySpark and Pandas) to analyze data about emoji usage. I have a string like `u'u+1f375'` or `u'u+1f618'` that I want to convert to  and  respectively.

I've read several other SO posts and the [unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type), trying to grasp `encode` and `decode` to no avail.

This didn't work:

```
decode_udf = udf(lambda x: x.decode('unicode-escape'))
foo = emojis.withColumn('decoded_emoji', decode_udf(emojis.emoji))
Result: decoded_emoji=u'u+1f618'
```

This ended up working on a one-off basis, but fails the moment I apply it to my RDD.

```
def rename_if_emoji(pattern):
  """rename the element name of dataframe with emoji"""

  if pattern.lower().startswith("u+"):
    emoji_string = ""
    EMOJI_PREFIX = "u+"
    for part_org in pattern.lower().split(" "):
      part = part_org.strip();
      if (part.startswith(EMOJI_PREFIX)):
        padding = "0" * (8 + len(EMOJI_PREFIX) - len(part)) 
        codepoint = '\U' + padding + part[len(EMOJI_PREFIX):]
        print("codepoint: " + codepoint)
        emoji_string += codepoint.decode('unicode-escape')
        print("emoji_string: " + emoji_string)
    return emoji_string
  else:
    return pattern

rename_if_emoji_udf = udf(rename_if_emoji)
```

Error: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\U0001f618' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: In python 2, u'u+1f618' is exactly the same thing (conceptually) as . It sounds like maybe your problem is that something (your terminal maybe?) isn't *rendering* the character the way you want? Can you give more detail on what you want to happen and where, and what is actually happening?

Comment: @TomDalton No, u'\U0001f618' is the same as u''.

Comment: Why not using a simple `.replace` on the unicode text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ability to print emoji correctly depends on the IDE/terminal used.  You'll get a `UnicodeEncodeError` on an unsupported terminal due to Python 2's `print` encoding Unicode strings to the terminal's encoding.  You also need font support.  You're error is on the `print`.  You've decoded it correctly but your output device ideally should support UTF-8.

The example simplifies the decoding process.  I print the `repr()` of the string in case the terminal isn't configured to support the characters being printed.

```
import re

def replacement(m):
    '''Assume the matched characters are hexadecimal, convert to integer,
       format appropriately, and decode back to Unicode.
    '''
    i = int(m.group(1),16)
    return '\\U{:08X}'.format(i).decode('unicode-escape')

def replace(s):
    '''Replace all u+nnnn strings with the Unicode equivalent.
    '''
    return re.sub(ur'u\+([0-9a-fA-F]+)',replacement,s)

s = u'u+1f618 u+1f375'
t = replace(s)
print repr(t)
print t
```

Output (on a UTF-8 IDE):

```
u'\U0001f618 \U0001f375'
```